# Using dedicated IP for mail and website (different from server)

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, dedicated-server

I currently rent a dedicated server with an IP 1.1.1.1 and I've added a domain with IP 1.1.1.2 with DNS records (domain.com/mail.domain.com), MX record, SPF record etc all pointing at 1.1.1.2

The problem is when I send an email from that domain in the header it shows the server's hostname and IP (1.1.1.1) instead of its dedicated IP. Is it possible to only show its dedicated IP and domain's hostname instead?

I am using Postfix & Dovecot on Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks!

Comment: what...
is that IP on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nano /etc/postfix/main.cf

add line:
smtp_bind_address = 1.1.1.2

restart postfix, send mail to test.